# Como instalar o pipenv no ubuntu 16.04 para python3

Tags: python, django

Eu tentei instalar utilizando `apt-get install pipenv`, `apt install pipenv` porém não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 1):

Para solução do problema supracitado, primeiramente tive que instalar o comando `pip`, utilizando `sudo apt install python3-pip` e posteriormente `sudo pip3 install pipenv`

[Documentação de Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv)

Comment: Que é como é citado na [documentação](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv). Você estava mesmo com o problema ou só postou a pergunta para poder respondê-la? Ficou confuso.

Comment: De qualquer modo editei a resposta para incluir o seu link @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @lazyFox "resposta" :)

Comment: Exacto, quem é que disse o contrário? XD

Comment: @lazyFox desculpe, é que eu tinha entrado no *DeLorean*, mas estou de volta no futuro agora :)

Comment: Instalar coisas com PIP direto no Python do sistema (isso é, fazendo `sudo pip ...` pode ser bem perigoso para que o sistema continue estável e atualizável e é desencorajado. Em particular se o pip instala um arquivo que depois esteja presente num pacote `.deb` do sistema, esse outro pacote não vai poder ser instalado ou atualizado. O caminho acima deve ser usado como último recurso.